# Data Binding strings formatadas perdendo formato

Tags: java, android, kotlin, binding, android-databinding

Aparentemente Data Binding para strings formatadas não funciona corretamente.

Por exemplo:

```
<string name="minhaString">Você tem um limite de <b>%s</b> reais.</string>
```

Se eu utilizar data binding `text=@{string/minhaString(500)}`

O resultado esperado: Você tem um limite de **500** reais.

O resultado obtido: Você tem um limite de 500 reais.

Ou seja, a parte de formatação para Bold não foi aplicada devido ao data binding. O uso de `@{String.format(string/minhaString(500))}` também não aplica o Bold.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Já tentou utilizando html? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823945/10526030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você aponta para o recurso de string diretamente, a TextView recebe um objeto do tipo Spanned, que implementa a interface CharSequence e que contém spans, elementos que fornecem o negrito, itálico, etc).

Quando você usa o DataBinding, a API de DataBinding faz a injeção dos valores mas retorna um objeto String, que também implementa CharSequence, mas os elementos Span foram perdidos na operação.

Conforme dito pelo @murillo-comino, é possível reinterpretar a String e gerar um objeto que possui os Span por meio da classe Html, de acordo com https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823945/10526030.

Porém, o método fromHtml mudou no API level 24 (Android N), então o mais correto atualmente (para compatibilidade entre as diferentes versões do Android) seria você utilizar

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

Para isso, é necessário incluir a dependência em seu projeto:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1
```

Assim, você deve inserir:
No arquivo strings.xml

```
<string name="minhaString">Você tem um limite de <b>%s</b> reais.</string>
```

No arquivo de Layout:

```
<import type="androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat"/>
```

No componente que recebe o texto:

```
android:text="@{HtmlCompat.fromHtml(@string/minhaString(500),HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Outra possibilidade é você utilizar um spannable, tal como:

`val span = SpannableString(this) span.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startBold, endBold, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)  return span`